# Slicing an array in redux store always results in removing the last array item on component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a Ruler component and when I click on it, it creates horizontal ruler lines for me by adding 1 more to my **redux store**. So far I have no problems when I am adding them, but I also want to remove these rules when I double click on them, I send the item index through the **action** to my **reducer**, where I run an `array.slice` to remove just the rule that I double clicked on. But no matter what, it just pops the last rule for me.

I know that this is somehow happening when I am rendering the component, since when I `console.log` the array in the reducer, the correct element is removed from it, but it renders differently. Here are the codes I have used:

**My Ruler component:**

```
class Rulers extends Component {
    render() {
        const { mousePosition, wheelY, dragY, rulerHGuides } = this.props;

        const ruleH = rulerHGuides.map((ruleH, i)=><RuleH index={i} wheelY={wheelY} dragY={dragY} key={i} {...ruleH} /> )

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="rules">
                    { ruleH }
                </div>
                <div className="ruler-horizontal" onClick={e=>{ store.dispatch( actions.rulerHGuides({top: mousePosition.y}) ) }}>
                    <span className="mouse-follow-h" style={{transform: `translateX(${mousePosition.x}px)`}}></span>
                    <svg id="svgH" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(state=>{
    const { mousePosition, rulerHGuides } = state;
    return { mousePosition, rulerHGuides }
})(Rulers)
```

**The RuleH component**

```
class RuleH extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            rulezHDrag: 0,
            top: 0
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { wheelY, dragY, index, id } = this.props;
        const { rulezHDrag, top } = this.state;

        return (
            <DraggableCore onDrag={this.handleRuleH.bind(this)} enableUserSelectHack={false}>
                <span id={id} className="ruleH" style={{top, transform: `translate3d(0, ${(-wheelY) + dragY + rulezHDrag}px, 0)`}}
                    onDoubleClick={e=>{
                        store.dispatch( actions.removeRulerHGuide( index ) )
                        console.log(index);
                    }}
                ></span>
            </DraggableCore>
        )
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            top: `${this.props.top - ((-this.props.wheelY) + this.props.dragY)}px`
        })
    }
    handleRuleH(e: MouseEvent, data: Object){
        const { rulezHDrag } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            rulezHDrag: rulezHDrag + data.deltaY
        })
    }
}
```

**My Action Creator:**

```
// Ruler guides
// ==========================================
export const rulerHGuides = (hGuides) => {
    return {
        type: 'RULER_H_GUIDES',
        hGuides
    }
}
export const removeRulerHGuide = (index) => {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE_RULER_H_GUIDE',
        index
    }
}
```

**My Reducer:**

```
export const rulerHGuides = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RULER_H_GUIDES':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.hGuides
            ]
        case 'REMOVE_RULER_H_GUIDE':
            return [
                ...state.slice(0,action.index),
                ...state.slice(action.index + 1)
            ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I have tried using `array.filters` instead of `array.slice`, but that is not the problem, the issue, whatever it is, is happening inside my component where I am mapping my `rulerHGuides` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using indices please use some form of unique `id` and assign it to a rule at the creation time. When you use indices as keys for React components, the same index is used as a key after item is removed which breaks the re-rendering optimization.

For example, having indices `0, 1, 2, 3` and removing the item at `2` you are left with `0, 1, 2` - there you can see the last key is removed which is causing the issue you described.

Comment: Basically, as you said, the whole thing was caused because I passed the array index as the component key. So what I did was to create a counter outside of my component, then assign that number as the key add 1 to the counter and continue. This way, it worked perfectly fine. So thank you very much.